# Elementor custom media control

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am currently trying to copy Elementor's plugin Media control to do some adjustments to it in wordpress. I tried copying the control from \Elementor\Control_Media changing the name of the class and this method:

```
class Control_Custom_Media extends \Elementor\Control_Base_Multiple {
    ...
    public function get_type() {
        return 'custommedia';
    }
}
```

Then registered it

```
function register_custom_controls($controls) {
    include 'control-custom-media.php';

    Plugin::instance()->controls_manager->register_control( 'custommedia', new Control_Custom_Media() );
}
add_action( 'elementor/controls/controls_registered', 'register_custom_controls');
```

Finally I created a widget with that control

```
protected function _register_controls() {
    ...
    $this->add_control(
        'image',
        [
            'label' => __( 'Test', 'custom-plugin' ),
            'type' => 'custommedia',
            'default' => [
                'url' => \Elementor\Utils::get_placeholder_image_src(),
            ],
        ]
    );
    ...
}
```

But I can't seem  to make it work. The field appears on the elementor sidebar but once I click to open the media library, it doesn't work. Checked the events and the one that fires the 'openFrame' event is not bind for some reason?

To test if the media control was working I added it after and that one works

[image]

What I could be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I ended up extending the Media control for my custom control and add it as a control view.

```
var customMediaView = elementor.modules.controls.Media.extend({
    onReady: function () {
        /* do stuff */
    }
});

elementor.addControlView('customMediaView', customMediaView);
```

On the enqueue method

```
wp_register_script( 'custommedia-control',  plugins_url('/custommedia-control.js', __DIR__), [ 'elementor-editor' ], '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'custommedia-control' );
```

Comment: Do you have full code how to extend this? I would like to use javascript to launch my  media uploader. Thanks

Comment: If you still need it I will try to put it in a gist on github.